# Использование LongPoll сервера

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Можете подсказать как с помощью метода **messages.getLongPollHistor**'y, считать входящее сообщение и дать на него ответ к примеру если, входящее сообщение было *"Привет"*, овтетить *"И тебе привет"*..
Я смог реализовать без использования **LongPoll**, просто через **message.get**, но это не совсем то что мне нужно, переделать точно так же только под **LongPoll** не получается.. Вот как я делал :

```
<?php
require_once "vk.api.php";

define('token', 'e495f5565966573062688ff988a83e5e39a45e3fb2a3ba7344cdb772545e7157a97259af8f1b3d386fb80');
$vk = new VK(token);

$messages = $vk->request('messages.get', [
'count' => '10',
]);
file_get_contents($messages);

echo "<pre>";
foreach ($messages['response'] as $message): 

if (!$message['read_state']) {

if ($dialog['body'] == 'Привет') {
       // sleep(1);
         $reading = $vk->request('messages.markAsRead', [
               'peer_id' => $dialog['uid'], 
           ]); 
          $typing = $vk->request('messages.setActivity', [
                'user_id' => $dialog['uid'], 
               'type' => 'typing',
          ]);
          $send = $vk->request('messages.send', [
              'message' => "Дарова",
              'attachment' => 'photo76386795_456239027',
              'uid' => $dialog['uid'],
          ]);
    }
    endforeach; 
echo "</pre>";
```